# Cakephp 3.8 create tree navigation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a navigation with submenus in cakephp 3.8.

I have setup the database with some fields, e.g. parent_id, lft, rght and level (and more).

What I already tried is creating my own menuhelper and added the following code in there:

```
public function showMenu($id)
{
    if (!$id) {
        return;
    }
    $menuitems = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('menuitems')->find('all')->where(['menu_item_menu_id' => $id])->order(['menu_item_position'=>'ASC']);
    $mbclass = $ismobile ? 'mb-3' : '';
    if ($menuitems) {
        $menu = "<div class='collapse navbar-collapse my-2 my-md-0' id='navbarToggler'><ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto mr-2 ".$mbclass ."'>";
        foreach ($menuitems as $items) {
            if ($items->level == 0) {

                $parent_id = $items->id;
                if ($items->parent_id == 0) {
                    $menu .= "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='".$items->slug."'><span class='menu-text'>".$items->menu_item_title."</span><span class='menu-bottom'></span></a>";
                }
            }
            if ($items->level == 1 || $items->level == 2) {
                if ($parent_id == $items->parent_id) {
                    $menu .= "<div class='dropdown-menu'>";
                        $menu .= "<a class='dropdown-item' href='".$items->slug."'>".$items->menu_item_title."</a>";
                    $menu .= "</div>";
                }
            }
            if ($items->level == 0) {
                if ($items->parent_id == 0) {
                    $menu .= "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        $menu .= "</ul>";
        $menu .= "<span class='sep d-sm-none d-md-block'></span>";
        $menu .= "<a class='btn btn-outline-success btn-login' href='/login'>Leden Inlog</a>";
        $menu .= "</div>";
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

On the view.ctp I added:

```
    <?= $this->Menu->showMenu(38) ?>
```

I have tried it with the information on the cakephp tree page: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html

But I can't get the submenu working.

**Update**

I have added Sehdev's comment and I am getting the submenu, only it is not inside the parents li element, it is just below there, which should not happen.

Basically it's shown like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <div>submenu</div>
</ul>
```

While it should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2
        <div>submenu</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to execute :
`$menus = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('menuitems');
$menus->recover();`

Comment: `if ($items->level == 0)` and  `if ($items->level == 1 || $items->level == 2) `  both execute on different iterations that is why you are getting this kind of output

Comment: It is in the same foreach loop, but is basically checking if the level is 1 or more, then should add a submenu. But doesn’t do that at the correct location. Should I check for submenus differently then?